# В tkinter python не перемещается объект

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Всем привет. Сегодня начал изучать tk, и столкнулся с проблемой, больше 1 отступа вниз текст не идет.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#--------
root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry('500x500')
#--------

def btnclicked():
    label.configure(text = 'Я ушёл!')

def randBtnDef():
    OutPutrand = random.choice(randText)

randText = list(range(1, 1000))

RandLabel = Label(text = 'Нажми на рандом кнопку', font = ('Helvetica', 15))
RandLabel.grid(column = 1, row = 5)
label = Label(text = 'Я здесь!', font = ('Helvetica', 20))
label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

btn = Button(root, fg = "red", text = "Нажми меня!", command = btnclicked)
btn.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

randBtn = Button(root, fg = "green", text = "Нажми для рандомной цифры от 1 до 1000", command = btnclicked)

root.mainloop()
```

Скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Эникейщик, этот текст - Нажми для рандомной цифры от 1 до 1000

Comment: И где он должен быть?

Comment: @Эникейщик Посмотри код, и увидишь что он внизу еще на 4 отступа должен быть

Comment: Не вижу. Где именно это указано?

Comment: @Эникейщик RandLabel = Label(text = 'Нажми на рандом кнопку', font = ('Helvetica', 15))
RandLabel.grid(column = 1, row = 5)

Comment: В первом комментарии у вас совсем о другом тексте речь. А этот текст показывается там, где и должен быть - пустые колонки и строки игнорируются.

Answer (score 1):

Все как и должно быть по документации: колонки и строки, которые ничего не содержат, игнорируются. В строках от 2 до 4 ничего нет, потому их и нет.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/471809)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov является ответом на вопрос. Все, что нужно было уточнить у автора, я уточнил. Если уж делаете проверки, то вникайте хотя бы.

Comment: Я не спорю с тем, что для данного автора это ответ. Но для других участников Ваш ответ будет малополезен без дополнительно прочтения комментариев и, возможно, документации. В стандартных комментах для тревоги соответствующего текста нет, писать сам, признаюсь, поленился.